# "find" command returning nothing when searching through absolute path

Tags: unix

Thought there might be a simple solution to this, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  It's a simple-enough problem.  Say I have the following folder/file structure:

```
/home/
    text1.txt
    /mydir/
        text2.txt
```

Then I input the command:

```
find . -name *.txt
```

This command returns "text1.txt" when called from within /home, and returns "text2.txt" when called from within /home/mydir, as it should.

However, when calling the following from /home...:

```
find /home/mydir -name *.txt
```

it returns nothing.  My expectation is that it would return "text2.txt."  Any thoughts?  I have already checked to see if I have any wayward aliases assigned to find, and I have nothing.

It is also worth it to note that I have two unix machines.  The use of an absolute path for "find" works on one machine and not the other.  Can't go into much more detail than that, I'm afraid.  Just looking for a direction to investigate this more.

Thanks to anyone who can help :-)

Comment: Try `find /home/mydir -name "*.txt"` (with quotes to prevent the shell from globbing).

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
find . -name "*.txt"
```

otherwise bash will extract *.txt to text1.txt resulting in the following command:

```
find . -name text1.txt
```

And it will no longer match text2.txt